# Where to post follow-up on answered question?

Tags: support, status-completed, questions, answered-questions

Recently I asked a [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72705/how-to-use-wildcard-to-append-multiple-feature-classes-in-modelbuilder) and received an answer.  It worked initially so I marked it as answered.   However as I used the model I came across a significant problem that I'd like to ask for further assistance with.

How should I ask for help on my follow-up question - on the same question or should I post a new question and link to my previous question?  I have searched in the "help" for this site and haven't found a definitive answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Post another question about the new problem, referencing the old one to avoid duplication of effort and narrowing the problem space down. So in the general good question style: *"I've had problems with A and /this/ fixed it, but now I have an additional constraint B and need help with adapting the model. I've tried C and D, but ..."*.